# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large when trying to POST into SQL

Tags: html, node.js, sql-server, angular, express

`PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large` I have this error when I try to POST something into SQL server (from Angular6)

This is what I want to post:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'john',
    'projects': ["P1", "P2", ... "P4500"] // so this is an array with 4500 elements
  }
]
```

I tried using:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));
```

but I still get the error.

This is my router if this helps:

```
router.post('/addMoreProjects', (req, res, next) => {
  var projArr = req.body.projects.split(',')
  for (var i in projArr ) {
    knex.from('users')
      .insert({
        name: req.body.name,
        projects: projArr[i]
      })
      .then((project) => {
        res.json(project);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
      })
  }
});
```

.ts

```
  addProject() {
    let project = {
      name: this.name,
      projects: this.projectsArray.toString()
    }
    this.projService.addMoreProjects(JSON.stringify(project)).then(() => {})
  }
```

service

```
  addMoreProjects(projectBody: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.rootURL + "/projects/addMoreProjects", projectBody, { headers: this.setHeaders() }).toPromise()
      .then((project) => {
        return project;
      }).catch((error) => {
        return error;
      })
  }
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your time!